# How to see events on RDS instance which is deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

One of RDS instance running within our account is deleted. We would like to find out who and when it is deleted.

Is there a way to find a log of that somewhere?
How can I see the events on RDS instance which is deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `when` can be checked form the *Events* of your RDS dashboard page:

[image]

You can retrieve events for your RDS resources through the AWS Management Console, which shows events from the past 24 hours

If it happened earlier, you can use the CLI which retrieves events up to 14 days

```
[xxx@xxxx ~]# aws rds describe-events --source-identifier test --source-type db-instance
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "Date": "2016-05-20T12:58:26.529Z",
            "Message": "DB instance deleted",
            "SourceIdentifier": "test",
            "EventCategories": [
                "deletion"
            ],
            "SourceType": "db-instance"
        }
    ]
}
```